# PHP Warning adding menu

Tags: menus, plugin-wpml, warnings

(sorry for my english...)
I have an issue...:

I can't add / translate menus in my admin. I have this error in debug.log :

> PHP Warning:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\www.guestonline.io\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 4670

Since i installed WPML, i had many errors with my DB (primary key and auto increment erased...). I corrected theses error easly (just with SQL), but for this new problem with Menus and Warning, i don't know what to do.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Please check the first parameter of the function stripe_tags from \wp-includes\formatting.php on line 4670. You can check the value of the parameter by using var_dump( $variable ) and if you get array then change the array to string and then pass the string in the function. You can also use the function is_array to check is this array or not.